# (Still) Stuck with Twitter Typeahead

Tags: javascript, php, remote-access, twitter-typeahead

If I use

```
var users_bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {url:'https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/typeahead.js/gh-pages/data/countries.json',
    filter: function (result) {
        return $.map(result, function (username) {
            return {
                name: username
            };
        });
    }
      }
});
```

with the json formatted as *["Andorra","United Arab Emirates","Afghanistan",...]* it works as expected, but I can't manage to receive the data returned by my .php file with

```
var users_bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {url:'./search.php?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: function (result) {
        return $.map(result, function (username) {
            return {
                name: username
            };
        });
    }
      }
});
```

(I only changed the part after remote...) The .php file receives the input and logs for example *["test01","test02"]* as answer to the input 't'. The last two lines of my php file are:

```
error_log(json_encode($results));
return json_encode($results);
```

So, how do I make my JS function receive the return value of my php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `returning` `json_encode` have you tried `echoing` it, and commenting out the error log to see what happens?

```
//error_log(json_encode($results));
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: no problem. although a more indepth answer can be created, for future reference, `php` doesn't `return` anything to client side (`ajax`). Ajax is just pulling back what gets displayed on the `php` page, so if nothing is displayed (ie `echo`ed), `ajax` won't see it either.